# Add a border color in my menu

Tags: html, css

I try to create an effect on my menu.

I try to add a 3px border on the top of each "li" in my menu. I would like that it's border appears on hover. But I didn't manage to.

I try with :after but nothing change.

```
#mm {
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e8e4e0;
}

#mm ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
}

#mm ul li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #372f7e;
    font-size: 9.2px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#mm ul li:hover {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    line-height: 46px;
}


<div id="mm">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Choice</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Choice</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Choice</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Choice</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Choice</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Choice</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your example in jsfiddle?

Comment: It looks like it works to me https://jsbin.com/mecuqezuke/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Works on the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jtn32bxg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is almost OK. It works but it looks terrible. It's better to have `border-top` with transparent color and then change it on hover:

```
#mm ul li {
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}

#mm ul li:hover {
    border-top-color: black;
}
```

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/infous/abmhtL4x/